# Write and Read from a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have been following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

So far is what I was searching for, but the only problem is that when i close and open the app again the file and the text is not saved anymore, so I want to the file be saved forever with the text.

I want to it be saved here http://gyazo.com/82e838cd2385cea7021647a8d39f49a8.png/level/batlevel.txt. So when I can open the app again the text that was write there it will be there

```
    private async void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await WriteToFile();

        // Update UI.
        this.btnWrite.IsEnabled = false;
        this.btnRead.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private async Task WriteToFile()
    {
        // Get the text data from the textbox. 
        byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());

        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        // Create a new folder name DataFolder.
        var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("level",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
        var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("level.txt",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // Write the data from the textbox.
        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    private async void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ReadFile();

        // Update UI.
        this.btnWrite.IsEnabled = true;
        this.btnRead.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private async Task ReadFile()
    {
        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        if (local != null)
        {
            // Get the DataFolder folder.
            var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("level");

            // Get the file.
            var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("level.txt");

            // Read the data.
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                this.textBlock1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to show us what you have attempted to do so far.

Comment: I did exactly as the tutorial said, from there I have no idea to do what I want to do :(

Comment: This might help: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Done, I added the code for you guys see

Comment: why are you calling `CreateFileAsync` with `ReplaceExisting`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be opening your **level.txt** file with the `OpenIfExists` option instead of `ReplaceExisting` :

```
// Create a new file named DataFile.txt.
var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync( "level.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists );
```