# Read file c# windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, readfile

few weeks ago I asked a similar question in this topic [Write and Read from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028344/write-and-read-from-a-file/19030311?noredirect=1#19030311) and my question was answered, but now I'm trying to read the file and use a if function, but at the moment I can only read from a textblock by pressing a button to read the file and transfer to the txtblock, so I want to know how to be able to read not using this way. At the moment here.

```
 private async Task ReadFile()
    {
        // Get the local folder.
        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        if (local != null)
        {
            // Get the DataFolder folder.
            var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("level");

            // Get the file.
            var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("level.txt");

            // Read the data.
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                this.textBlock1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
    }


    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await ReadFile();

        if (textBlock1.Text == "test")
            star2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ unclear.  What are you trying to write?

Comment: I assume the code you're posted isn't working? Where does it fail?

Comment: Hi really sorry about that! I have already wrote something on the file, I just want to be able to read it now without needing to transfer what is on it to a txtblock so I can be able to use the if function, to confirm if x == x. 
@canhazbits it works perfecly, but is working the way I explained for SLaks

Answer (score 1):

Took a second to figure out what I think you mean.

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            this.textBlock1.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Try this:

```
        string readtxt;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            readtxt = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Now you will have a string variable 'readtxt' that works in all the ways any string type would and contains the contents of your file.

Comment: thanks, but would be possible for me to use it in this case: if(readtxt == "x")
star2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
? Sorry for asking it, I'm kind of a beginner on c#!

Comment: It should be as long as your ReadFile method returns the value.  For examples of returning a value via async take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx.

Comment: Ok thanks I will study it and try to do, but do you have any other suggestions that I can do what I want to do in a different way? Or this is the only way?

Comment: You have to get the string created in ReadFile back to your Button_Click method for consumption.  You can use a global variable for this but given you are doing async operations you'd have to protect it with some sort of lock/semaphore/mutex/... using a global in this case is considered a "bad idea" ... but it works as a quick and dirty way to test.  The proper/best way is to have the string passed back which MS/C# has made very easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async Task ReadFile()
{
    // Get the local folder.
    StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    if (local != null)
    {
        // Get the DataFolder folder.
        var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("level");

        // Get the file.
        var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("level.txt");

        string = readtext
        // Read the data.
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            readtext = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        if (readtxt == "x")
                x do something
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Dweeberly for helping